# How to get a stable version from docker hub for open-liberty image?

Tags: docker, dockerhub, open-liberty

i am a bit confused because of the version and tag handling of the open-liberty image.
First: Whats the different between https://hub.docker.com/_/open-liberty and https://hub.docker.com/r/openliberty/open-liberty? Whats the right one?

I want to use a stable, not changing, version of the docker image for open-liberty.

At the moment i use this in my DOCKERFILE:
FROM open-liberty:kernel

But I want to use a stable version and dont know were to find.
If I look here: https://hub.docker.com/_/open-liberty?tab=description
I only can see variants but no versions of open-liberty.
I exspected something like that https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/wildfly/tags

On Github (https://github.com/OpenLiberty/ci.docker/tree/master/official) I can see the changes on the DOCKERFILE. So at the moment I pull the image I will get the current "commit". So every developer in my team has a different version of this image.

At the moment we use something like that:
FROM open-liberty:kernel@sha256:40fb5a0bdade0815d6e51be47b3f225551d645719da7b1029616334c429c8eb3

But that cant be the right solution.
Can anybody explain me the reason why there are no stable tags on the open-liberty image?

Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The differences between the Official vs Community version of Open Liberty are outlined in this [link](https://github.com/OpenLiberty/ci.docker#docker-hub-images).  Basically, the Community version (openliberty/open-liberty) predates the Official version (_/open-liberty), so now we keep it only for "extra" things like the daily images, a future home for sample app images, and Open Liberty images based on non-official images such as the current Java11 + OpenJ9 image.

In terms of versioning, you are right that currently using the SHA is the only approach, as discussed [here](https://github.com/OpenLiberty/ci.docker/issues/19).  We're considering adding image tags, so would be good if you could add your vote / opinion in that GitHub issue.